# Resend emails via Exchange WebService API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've the requirement to resend Emails that were already sent. I don't have to change anything on the mail, only resend it to the original recipients. In the outlook client, it' possible via Message tab, in the Move group, click Actions, and then click Resend This Message.

Comment: What have you so far? What's the current problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(...);
EmailMessage.send();
```